# hibernate, parameter not working for having clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am experiencing some problems with hibernate.
Following is ok

```java
    SelectionQuery<Long> idsq = session.createSelectionQuery
    (
        "select model.marca.firma.tara.id id from Automobil group by id having count(*)=4",
                    Long.class);
        List<Long> ids = idsq.getResultList();
```

But following throws exception on binding parameter

```java
    Long mx = 4;
    SelectionQuery<Long> idsq = session.createSelectionQuery
    (
            "select model.marca.firma.tara.id id from Automobil group by id having count(*)=:mx",
            Long.class);
    query.setParameter("mx", mx);
    List<Long> ids = idsq.getResultList();
```

I get following error on the call of `setParameter`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [mx], expecting one of []
```

Why is `expecting one of []` and empty set? Looks like it is not detecting my `:mx`. I tried separating with spaces, result is the same. Note, I don't experience such a problem with parameters in the `where` clause

Comment: If you have faithfully reproduced the problem code, then it appears to me that you are trying to set a parameter on the wrong query. `idsq` != `query`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The problem is reproduced as described. But what exactly means ```idsq``` != ```query```? How can I fix this problem without creating some ql/sql... string dynamically?

Comment: You are storing the reference to your query in a variable named `idsq`.  You are invoking `setParameter()` on an object referenced by variable `query`.  There is no reason to think that these two distinct variables refer to the same query object.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Bingo! Thank you!